# C# Regex for prepending underscore to any tag elements starting with number

Tags: c#, regex

What `Regex.Replace` pattern can I use to prepend an underscore before any tag elements starting with a number?

e.g.

`"<1ABC>Hello</1ABC><A8D>World</A8D><0>!</0>"`

would become

`"<_1ABC>Hello</_1ABC><A8D>World</A8D><_0>!</_0>"`

Comment: You should use a proper XML parser, of which C# has quite a few. Obligatory read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/14868997

Answer (score 1):

This regex can get same result, but I'm sure there could be better ones.

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string input = @"<1ABC>Hello</1ABC><A8D>World</A8D><0>!</0>";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(</?)(\d[\d\w]*?)(>)", @"$1_$2$3");
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

@Lei Yang's answer will fail if an element has attributes. Minimal change is required:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string input = @"<1ABC id='abc'>Hello</1ABC><A8D>World</A8D><0>!</0>";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(</?)(\d.*?)([ >])", @"$1_$2$3");
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```cs
private static Regex rxTagsWithLeadingDigit = new Regex(@"
  (</?)    # open/close tag start, followed by
  (\d\w+)  # a tag name that begins with a decimal digit, followed by
  (\s|/?>) # a whitespace character or end-of-tag
", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

public string ensureTagsStartWithWordCharacter( string s )
{
  return rxTagsWithLeadingDigit.Replace( s , "$1_$2$3" );
}
```